# Confused on Nahor and Haran

Tags: names, geography, parashat-noach, abraham, cities

In Genesis 11, we are shown that Abram, Nahor, and Haran are brothers. Haran dies in Ur.

Then, Abram and other family members travel now to a city called Haran (a bit confusing, but okay. Did they found the city and name it after the deceased brother or something?). No mention of Nahor and what happened to him.

Then, Genesis 24, Abraham wants to find a wife for his son from his hometown. Where is his hometown? Is it Ur (where his father is from) or Haran (which is where the family spent some time)?

Then, a servant goes out and makes his way to the "town of Nahor." Where is that?

I looked on Google for all sorts of map but I can't find a city called "Nahor." I found one map with a colored line describing the travels of the servant and it ends in the city of Haran. So is "town of Nahor" = "Haran " = "Abraham's hometown"? I am so confused.

Comment: See too Genesis 22.

Comment: I don't understand.  I believe the only part in there is the listing of the family tree of Nahor.  There is no mention in there on what city is what.

Comment: You said "No mention of Nahor and what happened to him." I was filling you in. Also, עיר נחור probably means "Nahor's city" not "the city [called] _Nahor_".

Comment: Also, when Eliezer meets Laban, he is in Aram Naharayim (=Abraham's homeland) but when Jacob meets Laban, Laban is in Haran.

Comment: Note that the man is הָרָן  and the town is חָרָן; the first begins with a *hei* and the second with a *chet*. Sadly, many transliterate both as "h" when "ch" would be better for the latter.  (Same problem: "Hanukah"/"Chanukah".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following excerpt comes from Powell, M. A. (Ed.). (2011). The *HarperCollins Bible Dictionary* (Revised and Updated) (Third Edition.). New York: HarperCollins, p.680.

[image: Nahor]

Also, please see the Wikipedia citation for this ancient city - please click [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haran_(biblical_place)).